# A pr0blem with python virtualenv when I used it for the first time

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

It's my first time to try virtualenv and I got this. I searched the Internet but I can get a suitable answer for me.
I am currently running:
Mac OS: 10.12
Here is the problem:

```
fangyuxsMacBook:~ fANgyUXIn$ virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/Users/fANgyUXIn/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/fANgyUXIn/env/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpython3.5m.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/fANgyUXIn/env/bin/python
Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/fANgyUXIn/env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/fANgyUXIn' (should be   '/Users/fANgyUXIn/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Thank you!